# WPF double animation set wrong value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simple code to animate movement on canvas. The problem is that after animation completed element does not have proper value.

Here is example:

```
<Canvas Name="_canvas" >
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292"  Canvas.Left="56" Canvas.Top="26">
    <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Completed="Timeline_OnCompleted">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="264" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"/>                       
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>       
</Canvas>
```

And in code behind

```
private void Timeline_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Content = "Top is " + Canvas.GetTop(button1) + "and should be 264";
}
```

Result after complete an animation is

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in WPF: The storyboard's Completed event fires before the contained timelines are completed (see [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/566044/storyboard-completed-event-fired-before-all-child-timelines-completed)).

If you handle the Completed event on your DoubleAnimation instead, it will show the correct end value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like OnCompleted is called before the last animation step is done. If you really need to read button's Top position (i.e. getting `DoubleAnimation.To` is not acceptable), try running `Canvas.GetTop(button1)` when application will be idle (or try other priorities of dispatcher).

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(
        () => button1.Content = "Top is " + Canvas.GetTop(button1) + "and should be 264"
    ),
    DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle
);
```